# Python web scraping style content

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, html-parsing

I just want to pull data from HTML by using python.(I need `data = 20%`)
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="ratings-container">
  <div class="ratings">
    <div class="ratings active" style="width: 20%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to get the style content. The following similar code's result is NULL:

```py
mratingNew = (tag.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ratings active"})) 
for i in range(len(muserName)): 
    print(mratingNew[i].['style'])
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any specific errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get width with using `find` and can split it according to `:`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="ratings-container">
  <div class="ratings">
 <div class="ratings active" style="width: 20%"></div>
   </div>
     </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
finddiv = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'ratings active'})
style = finddiv['style']

style = style.split(':',1)[-1]
print style
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 20%
```

If you have more than one width with the same class name like :

```
html = '''<div class="ratings-container">
 <div class="ratings">
 <div class="ratings active" style="width: 20%"></div>
 <div class="ratings active" style="width: 40%"></div>
 <div class="ratings active" style="width: 30%"></div>
   </div>
     </div>'''
```

You need to use `findAll` and split it one by one

```
find_last_div = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'ratings active'})
for width_value in find_last_div:
    width_Get = width_value['style'].split(':',1)[-1]
    print width_Get
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 20%
 40%
 30%
```